# Fast Calculation of Pairwise Cosine Directional Distance Between Points in a (n x d x t) matrix

Tags: performance, matlab, distance, cosine-similarity

I am aware of the pdist(X,distance) in Matlab to take an (nxd) matrix of points and calculate the pairwise distances between them. I am also aware that it has an extra option to calculate the cosine distance if a matrix contain vectors rather than points.

What I would like to do is take a (n x d x t) matrix, which holds the varying positions of samples over time t and efficiently / quickly calculate the cosine directional distance between all pairs / all frames, where a v(t) is defined as the direction as calculate by p(t+1) - p(t), and p(t) refers to the row M(p,:,t).

Obviously I don't want to be using loops if can be helped. Any suggestions?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: You want to calculate the distance between all possible pairs, so `(n * t)(n * t - 1)/2` total distances? It would help if you clarified your second paragraph.

Comment: No...I want to calculate the distance between all pairs of vectors Vi and Vj...where vector Vi = pi(t+1) - pi(t) ...and pi(t) is stored as the column A(:,i,t). i.e the matrix A just stores all the positions of all points over time. NOT DIRECTIONAL VECTORS.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that the cosine distance is the same as twice the Euclidean distance between normalized vectors. This saves us from computing the norm over and over in the cosine distance function.

It sounds like you want the distances between the vector difference with each change in time. Is that correct?

```
data = diff(data,1,3);
[m,n,nt] = size(data);
data = reshape(data,m*nt,n);
data = data./repmat(sqrt(sum(data.^2,2)),1,n);
d = pdist(data);
d = d/2; %# The uniform scaling may not matter to you.
```

Comment: "Assuming you mean all pairs of vectors"...each column is a 3d position in time. I need to calculate the directional vector between each time period and then cosine distance.

Comment: data = data./reshape(sqrt(sum(data.^2,2)),1,3); ...what is the 1, 3?...and it errors when I try it. "To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change."

Comment: My bad, meant to say `repmat`.